# How do I validate an entry on an email using regex?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a reg expression to check for entry XXXXX between store locator and Store number in an email.

Store Locator: XXXXXX
Store Number:

Comment: What are valid characters in the store locator?  Numeric, alpha, whitespace?

Comment: Unless, you tell us what "Store Location" and "Store Number" looks like as well as what character XXXXXX might contains. I don't think we can really give you reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Store Locator: (.*?) Store Number

You can user [Regex Buddy](http://gofrom.us/4Q6) to help you and test.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the store locator can include any non-whitespace characters:

```
^Store Locator:\W+(?<locator>\w+)
```

I like [Derek Slager's site](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) for .NET-specific regex validation.

Comment: Slager's regex is down.  Here's an alternate https://dotnetonlinetools.com/A-Better-Dotnet-Regular-Expression-Tester

Answer (score 0):

If the XXXXX is numeric, you could use Store Locator: ([0-9]+) Store Number for bonus validation.